# Python: Failed to import installed module pdpbox

Tags: python, package

I installed the pdpbox package through pip.

```
pip install pdpbox
Requirement already satisfied: pdpbox in c:\users\Me\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (0.2.1)
```

And within Spyder, I did `!pip list`. The package showed up.

`PDPbox                        0.2.1`

Yet when I tried to do `from pdpbox import pdp, get_dataset, info_plots` or `from PDPbox import pdp, get_dataset, info_plots`, i received `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdpbox'`. I restarted the Spyder IDE and the error still occurred

What have I done wrong here ?

**UPDATE:**

I tried (1) restarting Spyder, (2) `pip3 install pdpbox`, still no luck.

Originally, when I first tried to install it within the Spyder IDE `!pip install pdpbox` which resulted in an error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\Me\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\ft2font.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

So the package was installed via `pip install pdpbox --user`. I believe the `--user` is causing all of these trouble.

**Final Update:**

I found the fix. With the `--user` option, the package was being installed in `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages`, which was not added into the PYTHONPATHmanager in Spyder. That's why module was never found.

Comment: try restarting the ide

Comment: I tried. Still getting same error

Comment: `pip --version` output  Python 3.7.9

Comment: it could also be because the actual module is not named pdpbox, it could be some sort of shortened form, take a look at the directory where You installed the library

Comment: c:\users\Me\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages take a look here and see how it is called there

Comment: pip3 is available although i have never used.

Comment: Within `c:\users\Me\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages`, there exists `PDPbox-0.2.1` and `PDPbox-0.2.1-py3.7.egg`. I tried `from PDPbox import pdp, get_dataset, info_plots` and got the same error.

Comment: ok, try importing it as `from PDPbox-0.2.1 import *` that couuld work, obvs if it works You can import the specific modules

Comment: `from PDPbox-0.2.1 import *` results in `Syntax Error` due to the `-`

Comment: tried `pip3`. Again, it says `Requirement already satisfied: pdpbox in c:\users\Me\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (0.2.1)`. Do I have to unistall pdpbox first before installing it with `pip3` ?

Comment: prob no in this case

Comment: When I tried to do `python3 -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths())'` on command line. `Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.`

Comment: However, within Spyder , I did `import sysconfig;print(sysconfig.get_paths()) `, it returns

Comment: `{'stdlib': 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\Lib', 'platstdlib': 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\Lib', 'purelib': 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages', 'platlib': 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages', 'include': 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\Include', 'platinclude': '

Comment: C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\Include', 'scripts': 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\Scripts', 'data': 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python'}`

Comment: does [this](https://forums.fast.ai/t/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pdpbox/25871/7) help?

Comment: btw what does name of the directory `c:\users\Me\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages` in correct case? I notice they are set to lower-case for some reason. Could you check your directory?

Comment: Also could you try the code `import sys; print(sys.path)`? What does it output?

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.path)` output the following: `['C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\pkgs', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\pkgs\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\CV\\2021',

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ML', '', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\pkgs', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\.ipython']`

Comment: I remember the first time I tried to install the package. I had to `pip install pdpbox --user`. Because without adding `--user`, it would result in an error in installation. I believe it's the `--user` option that is causing error.

Comment: Is the `roaming` directory actually named `Roaming` at `C:\Users\Me\AppData` in your Files Exporer? Or is it `ROAMING`?

Comment: Yes, it's named `Roaming`.

Comment: Could you try this code before the running your code? `import sys; sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages')` Does it work now?

Comment: I updated my solution above . Your solution works too. Basically, installing with `--user` option will install the package in a different location, which i didn't add to the system path. Now it's resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. That's great then